# How to modify each element of an array in jq

Tags: jq

Suppose I have a JSON:

```
[
    {
        "title": "Title1",
        "reference": [
            "123"
        ]
    },
    {
        "title": "Title2",
        "reference": [
            "234",
            "345"
        ]
    }
]
```

Id like to modify each element of the reference array so that the reference appears twice. I'd like to achieve:

```
[
    {
        "title": "Title1",
        "reference": [
            "123 is 123"
        ]
    },
    {
        "title": "Title2",
        "reference": [
            "234 is 234",
            "345 is 345"
        ]
    }
]
```

I've tried:

```
jq '.[] | .reference = [("\(.reference[]) is \(.reference[])")]'
```

but this fails where the array has more than one item:

```
{
  "title": "Title1",
  "reference": [
    "123 is 123"
  ]
}
{
  "title": "Title2",
  "reference": [
    "234 is 234",
    "345 is 234",
    "234 is 345",
    "345 is 345"
  ]
}
```

How can I modify the above jq to achieve the desired result?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work just fine:

```
jq '.[].reference[] |= "\(.) is \(.)"'
```

It replaces every item of the reference arrays with a string which contains itself two times and the word "is"

Answer (score 3):

```
map(.reference |= map(. + " is " + .))
```

Will change each `.reference` to be `.reference is .reference`

---

```json
[
  {
    "title": "Title1",
    "reference": [
      "123 is 123"
    ]
  },
  {
    "title": "Title2",
    "reference": [
      "234 is 234",
      "345 is 345"
    ]
  }
]
```

[Demo](https://www.devtoolsdaily.com/jq_playground/?#%7B%22inputText%22%3A%22%5B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5C%22title%5C%22%3A%20%5C%22Title1%5C%22%2C%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5C%22reference%5C%22%3A%20%5B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5C%22123%5C%22%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5D%5Cn%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%5Cn%20%20%20%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5C%22title%5C%22%3A%20%5C%22Title2%5C%22%2C%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5C%22reference%5C%22%3A%20%5B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5C%22234%5C%22%2C%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5C%22345%5C%22%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5D%5Cn%20%20%20%20%7D%5Cn%5D%22%2C%22filterExpr%22%3A%22map(.reference%20%7C%3D%20map(.%20%2B%20%5C%22%20is%20%5C%22%20%2B%20.))%22%2C%22rawOutput%22%3Afalse%7D)